# HTTPS communication security

Tags: encryption, https, public-key-encryption

I have an ambiguity about HTTPS communication and my question had may be asked but I didn't find and clear response:
In HTTPS communication, the server is sharing it's public key with "everyone"
If this key is shared with public, than doesn't anyone can decrypt the communication from the server?

Comment: The other name commonly used for public key cryptography is *asymmetric* cryptography. The whole point is that different keys are used for encryption and decryption. (Also, note that the server's public key is only briefly relevant whilst the connection is being established. During the process, session keys will be generated and used during the remainder of the session)

Answer (score 0):

No. You use the public key to encrypt the data and it's not possible to decrypt it by using the same public key.

The only way to decrypt the data is by using the correspondent private key.

This [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) explains the core.